# Odoo add function to defaul create action

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I've got this function

```
def add_default_docs(self):
for r in self:
    id = self.id 
    labs_archive_journal_type_id = r.journal_type_id.id 
    archive_doc_name_ids = self.env['labs.archive.journal_type'].search([('id', '=', labs_archive_journal_type_id)]).archive_doc_name_ids 
    for n in archive_doc_name_ids:  
        self.env['labs.archive.document'].create({ 
                    "archive_journal_id": id,  
                    "name": n.id })
```

How could I call it when I press 'Create' button and create new record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever model you want to fire this function on creation on new model, inherit that model if that model is odoo built-in or if your own model, within that model definition inherit `create` method as following:

```
class ClassName(models.Model)
  _inherit = 'model.name'

  @api.multi
  def create(self, vals):
    records = super(ClassName, self).create(vals)
    records.add_default_docs()
    return records
```

If your model is defined in your own custom module, you can just insert this create function within that model definition, you won't need to inherit in new class.